# PHP download file sometimes speed is 0

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, download, response

The Firefox can pop download box when click download button , but sometime the speed is 0kb/s when click save file， nginx :1.4.6, php:7.0

[image]

After a while the network timeout:

[image]

In chrom,  the speed is 0kb/s when the file download a little

This situation will probably be downloaded 3 times.And show this situation when the file more than 500k

controller: Route function

```
    $response = new BinaryFileResponse($filePath, 200, [
        'Content-Type' => 'text/csv',
        'Content-Disposition' => 'attachment; filename="orders.csv"',
        'Content-Length' => filesize($filePath),
    ]);

    return $response;
```

I try more way:

1. I use symfony `bin/console server:start -e prod`, Its right
2. Use redirect to nginx server in controller,Its right

But use nginx and php is bad.

Hope you help me!
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

I check out the nginx log and find out， `open() "/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi/*" failed (13: Permission denied)`. After checking information， I know fastcgi_buffer_size is limit 64k, so my download file size about 64k or so.

The folder '/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi' my user not has power， so `chmon -R user /var/lib/nginx/fastcgi`, Its all right!!!